# UE4 UUserWidget is always changed after restarting UE4 or compile at blueprint editor

Tags: unreal-engine4

MyHUD.h

```
UCLASS()
class FPS_API AMyHUD : public AHUD
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

    UPROPERTY(EditDefaultsOnly, Category = Gameplay)
    class UUserWidget* DefaultWidget;
...
}
```

I make Blueprint BP_MyHUD extends MyHUD and Widget Blueprint. The problem is, the DefaultWidget in BP_MyHUD is set None after i restart UE4 program or compile using button in toolbar at Blueprint editor. How can i fix the value of DefaultWidget in BP_MyHUD?

Comment: Did you by any means set a default value for this variable? The property is exposed but if you recompile this reference might be lost as the base class is being reevaluated.

Comment: @Fritz But other variables, for example texture and skeletal mesh aren't lost value. Why it's happened only for UUserWidget?

Comment: @Fritz + And i didn't set a default value for DefaultWidget on AMyHUD. I set the value of DefaultWidget at only blueprint extends AMyHUD.

Answer (score 0):

By default variables are set to "Private" and thus can't be modified in derived classes.

Try putting this UPROPERTY after you say public: (you could also use protected:)

```
UCLASS()
class FPS_API AMyHUD : public AHUD
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

public:

    UPROPERTY(EditDefaultsOnly, Category = Gameplay)
    class UUserWidget* DefaultWidget;
...
}
```

Also I am unsure of the **EditDefaultsOnly** specifier when it comes to blueprints.  My understanding was without

> BlueprintReadWrite

You could not edit the variables in blueprints.  But if you've been using this with success with other variables it is likely not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party, but here's the answer:

**It's not possible.**

Non-BindWidget pointers with `EditDefaultsOnly` indeed generate a selector in the Details panel, but this selector **is not meant to select a widget inside** our component's archetype. It's **meant to select a widget outside** an instance of our component (it also need to be public and maybe a `BlueprintReadWrite` too). In this case, the value you put in the selector indeed stay across builds.

Sadly, this error-inducing selector appearing anyway means that two things aren't quite working properly around this behaviour :

- At the moment UE clears the selector when you're building, it should really display a warning/error explaining why
- You shouldn't really be able to put `EditAnywhere`/`EditDefaultsOnly` on a non-BindWidget property, only a `EditInstanceOnly`... yet there's no warning/error either =(

*(credits to [@Bohdon Sayre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10192823/bohdon-sayre) from BenUI's discord community for helping me on this one)*

Answer (score 0):

I was not satisfied by the previous answers, if anyone runs into the same problem, here is what you can do:

- Declare a SubClassOf to be able to select your widget
- Instantiate the widget in beginPlay() and store its pointer
- Use the pointer to do whatever you want with your widget instance

> ```
> /// IN YOUR HEADER
>
> UCLASS()
> class FPS_API AMyHUD : public AHUD
> {
>   GENERATED_BODY()
>
>     /* The widget you want to select */
>   UPROPERTY(EditDefaultsOnly, Category = Gameplay)
>   TSubclassOf<UUserWidget> BP_DefaultWidget;
>     
>     /* The instance of your widget to use */
>   UPROPERTY(Transient, Category = Gameplay)
>   UUserWidget* DefaultWidgetInstance;
> ...
> }
>   
>   
> /// IN YOUR CPP
>
> void AMyHUD::BeginPlay()
> {
>   Super::BeginPlay();
>
>   if (BP_DefaultWidget)
>   {
>       DefaultWidgetInstance = CreateWidget<UUserWidget>(GetWorld(), BP_DefaultWidget, FName("DefaultWidget"));
>       DefaultWidgetInstance->AddToViewport();
>   }
> }
> ```